# Execute an update using single-quoted columns in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am writing some tests for our SQL code and have some defined tables:

```
class CompanyAddressORM(Base):

    __tablename__ = "company_address"

    pk = Column("pk", Text, primary_key=True)
    project_id = Column("PROJECT_ID", Integer)
    company_id = Column("COMPANY_ID", Integer)


class CompanyDocumentsORM(Base):
    __tablename__ = "company_documents"

    pk = Column("pk", Text, primary_key=True)
    project_id = Column("PROJECT_ID", Integer)
    company_id = Column("COMPANY_ID", Integer)
    page_id = Column("PAGE_ID", Integer)
```

Our underlying code uses snowflake so I must not change it, but instead run the queries and mock the connection to snowflake using the testing.postgresql package.

I'm running into issues when trying to query items that are case sensitive.  E.g.

```
session.execute("select PROJECT_ID from company_address")
>>> *** sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "project_id" does not exist

session.execute('select "PROJECT_ID" from company_address').all()
>>> [(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)]
```

The problem comes in later when somewhere in the code we do an update with this query:

```
column_names = ", ".join(columns)
source_column_names = ", ".join(f"source.{col}" for col in columns)
target_column_updates = ", ".join(f"target.{col} = source.{col}" for col in columns)

# Generate the join condition for the merge query
join_condition = " AND ".join(
    f"target.{col} = source.{col}" for col in join_columns
)

# Perform the merge operation in Snowflake
merge_query = f"""
    MERGE INTO {table_name} as target
    USING {temp_table_name} as source
    ON {join_condition}
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
        {target_column_updates}
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
        ({column_names})
    VALUES ({source_column_names})
"""
cursor.execute(merge_query)
```

The original query runs fine in Snowflake but in sqlalchemy breaks because of case-insensitivity, so i must double quote all the cols:

```
source_column_names = ", ".join(f'''"source.{col}"''' for col in columns)
target_column_updates = ", ".join(f'''"target.{col}" = "source.{col}"''' for col in columns)

# Generate the join condition for the merge query
join_condition = " AND ".join(
    f'''"target.{col}" = "source.{col}"''' for col in join_columns
```

This will give me a query like this:

```
query = 'MERGE INTO company_address as target
    USING company_address_tmp as source
    ON "target.project_id" = "source.project_id"
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
        .....
```

but when I try to execute this query, I get a compilation error.

If i remove the double quotes:

````
LINE 4:         ON target.COMPANY_ID = source.COMPANY_ID AND target....```

What's the best way of dealing with this?
````

Comment: I tried this already but it also gives me a compilation error. I think i solved my problem by making lowercasing the column names in the ORM definition to make it case insensitive.

Comment: Psycopg2 provides [tools for composing SQL strings](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html); use those instead of trying to do it manually.